# How can I let Mathematica write $2+2x+\frac{1}{2}(1+2x)^2$ in the form: $1+2(x+\frac{1}{2})+2(x+\frac{1}{2})^2$

Tags: polynomials

How can I let Mathematica write $2+2x+\frac{1}{2}(1+2x)^2$ in the form: $1+2(x+\frac{1}{2})+2(x+\frac{1}{2})^2$

I have tried with `Collect` but failed:

```
Collect[Normal[Series[E^g[x], {g[x], 0, 2}]] /. g[x] -> 2 x + 1, 
 x + 1/2]
```

Comment: `Normal[Series[E^g[x], {g[x], 0, 2}]] /. g[x] -> 2 (x + 1/2)`? In general it's hard to get it not to combine loose-hanging constants. An internal rule in `Plus` combines them.

Comment: Expand as a series around `x=-1/2`. Then use `Normal`.